# Finding a pixel location in a field of view

Tags: math, camera, location, geocoding

So I have a camera with a defined field of view a point of a place I would like to label in the image. I have both the lat and lon of the points and I know the angle between them however my equation for finding the pixel location is off. Attached is an image to help my explanation:
[image]

I can solve for each vector of the camera to the center of view and the point and the full angle of the field of view and the angle between the center of view and point.

Here is what Im currently using: [angle of the field of view(green angle)/ the angle between the vectors (the blue angle)] * 1024 (screen width)

With numbers: (14.182353/65) * 1024 = 223.426620 and on the image the pixel value should be 328...

Another way I tried it was using a bearing equation: [[the bearing of the point to the camera- the bearing of the left side of the field of view ]/field of view] * 1024

With numbers: ((97.014993-83.500000)/65) * 1024 = 212.913132 and the answer should be 328...

Can anyone think of a more accurate solution?

[image]

Comment: Could you label what should be 328 in your picture?

Comment: 328 is the x value for of the pixel the point should be located on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `512(1-tan(blue)/tan(green/2))`, where blue is positive to the left.

If blue is to the right, you can treat it as a negative number, to get `512(1+tan(blue)/tan(green/2))`.

**Explanation:**

Let `C` be the camera, `d` be the dot labeled `328`, `E` be the center of the field of view, and `L` be the left end point of the field of view, so that you want to find `dL`.  Then (for blue going left):

```
dL+dE = EL = 512
tan(green/2)=EL/CE
tan(blue)=dE/CE
```

Then `tan(blue)/tan(green/2) = dE/EL = (512-dL)/512`, and you can solve for `dL`.

Going right would be similar (or you can work with negative distances, and everything works out fine).

Comment: Wow that worked! Thank you so much! How did you think of this? Is there a way to modify this if the blue is to the right?

Comment: @user2125844 I've updated my answer.  Let me know if you still have any questions.